# Select a row in a table where A and B exist but not C

Tags: sql

I have a table that has two primary keys.
One is a number 1,2,3 (PK) , the second key is a IniqueIdentifier(PK, FK).
You can have the uniqueIdentifier(Guid) 3 times but the first key is what is unique

I am looking for all rows where Key Numbers 1 and 2 exist and where Key Number '3' does not exist. How can I do that?

Comment: At least to me question is not clear. Add sample data of your table and expected results

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. (May consist of 1, 2 or even more columns.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from table1 t
where key = 1
and exists (select key from table1 where uniqueidentifier = t.uniqueidentifier and key = 2)
and not exists (select key from table1 where uniqueidentifier = t.uniqueidentifier and key = 3)
```

Comment: "key" here is the PK you mentioned(1,2,3)